# Entity Framework dbSet does not contain a definition for getAll ()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created this method, however the error described below appears to me, does anyone know a possible solution?

> dbSet does not contain a definition for getAll ()

```
public IEnumerable<Reserva> GetBookingsByRoomId(int Id)
{
    HotelEntities db = new HotelEntities();
    var allBookings = db.Reserva.GetAll().ToList();
    var bookings = (from Quarto
                    in db.Quarto
                    where Quarto.ID_Quarto == Id
                    select Quarto
                   ).ToList();
    return Mapper.Map<List<Reserva>, List<Reserva>>(bookings);
}
```

Comment: It is weird that you're not using `allBookings ` at all in your method. So why retrieving the data?

Comment: Where does the idea come from you need to call `GetAll()`? Is this a convention in the project, or did you find it in some tutorial?

Comment: I found in an example, I have solved this part, however in another method, I get an error...  impossible to converte System.datetime? to System.datetime

Comment: " I have solved this part," - then _delete_ this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
var allBookings = db.Reserva.ToList();
```

without worrying about any kind of "GetAll" method. That will get you all records by default.

Comment: Now, i got an error ... impossible to converte System.datetime? to System.datetime.... in other function

Comment: That's unlikely to be directly related to this piece of code. I have answered the question you asked, so if it helped you please mark it as accepted - thanks :-)

Comment: It sounds like in your other code, the error is because you have a Nullable datetime variable, and you try to assign its value to a datetime variable which is not nullable. It's impossible to do this because there if the original value happens to be null, it cannot tell the regular datetime variable to become null, since that's not allowed for that type. So your options are either to make both of the variables into nullable types, or do a cast from the nullable to non-nullable datetime before doing the assignment.If you need more help than this comment gives, please ask a new question about it